# If the median is not in the array while choosing the pivot by median of elements method, Quicksort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

edit: "select the median of 3 randomly chosen elements of the array as pivot" this is the statement on my assignment, which lead me to ask this question here. I could not understand how to choose the pivot by median of three randomly chosen elements.

---

I am looking for various methods for choosing the pivot in quicksort. I encountered this median one. However, one thing I did not understand, let's say our array is:

```
[1, 2, 9, 14, 73]
```

Choosing first-middle-last and calculating their median gives `(1+9+73)/3 = 27.6` it is pretty straightforward. However, I do not have an element in the array with this value apparently. What will I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't 9 the median of 1, 9, and 73 as opposed to the average?

Comment: @Surt yes, I had a misunderstanding on that, however, after learning this, what is the meaning of first-middle-last thing then? Its median is always the middle one.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're calculating the mean, or the average. When the array is ordered, the median is the middle-est value, or the average of 2 middle values. For your example, the median is 9

Comment: ok, I have the following statement in my assignment, "select the median of 3 randomly chosen elements of the array as pivot", so can you explain it regarding this statement?

Comment: choosing the median of 3 randomly chosen values in the array means that you randomly choose 3 values (lets say you choose a, b, and c, where a <= b <= c), and you would choose the value that is in the middle, namely b in this case, as your pivot